# solve the equation $z-2\bar{z}+7-6i=0$ for $z=a+ib$ where $\bar{z}=a-ib$

Tags: complex-analysis

L could not solve it. May I have some help?
How can I find $z$ in order to find $\bar{z}$? 
No idea came to my mind to try it.

Comment: Have you substituted appropriately?

Comment: **Hint:** Let $w$ be a complex number, then $ \quad w=0\quad\iff\quad \Re(w)=\Im(w)=0$.

Comment: Alt. hint: take the complex conjugates on both sides to get $\,z'-2z+7+6i=0\,$, then eliminate $\,z'\,$ between the two to get an equation in $\,z\,$ alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: $z-2z'=-a+3bi$ for $z=a+bi$.

Comment: I got it thanks a lot. Would you please help me with this for the same question (z^2=i)??

Comment: @Ms.Awad Had you already the Moivre's theorem?